# Isn't the term "foreign national" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

Looking at the definition given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_national (I know, not a great source) I can't see how replacing this with just "foreigner" wouldn't suffice?

Comment: Did you read the link you supplied? It says "The term "foreign national" came into usage when the previously used term "foreigner" developed negative connotations. They are synonyms."

Comment: I see that, but compared to "alien" I refute perceived negative connotations as a basis for the adoption of _foreign national_ rather than foreigner.

Answer (score 5):

*Foreign national* focuses on the citizenship of the person: the Oxford dictionary states it is "a person who is not a naturalized citizen of the country in which they are living". Whereas a *foreigner* is an "outsider" for some criterion (e.g. birth place or ancestry), not necessarily for their citizenship. Some people would qualify as *foreigners* people who've been naturalized and therefore are not *foreign nationals*.

Comment: I agree with this. If I move to China and obtain Chinese citizenship, I would no longer be a foreign national. Being a pasty-white European guy living in China, though, I would still very much be a _foreigner_ there.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, you are right that *foreigner* is a perfectly acceptable substitute. In normal usage this is the case.  However, the word *foreigner* can carry derogatory connotations.

The use of *foreign national* is intended to emphasise that no negative meaning is intended.  Especially if the speaker believes that the listener might make a negative inference.

Comment: The position is more complex in Britain since our law recognises 'dual nationality'. Many people, as well as being British possess another nationality. Indeed many 'British' people (of Arabic/Muslim descent) are currently fighting for ISIS forces in Syria and Iraq, whilst the UK government, with its American ally,  is inclined to the other side. Are such people 'foreigners'?

Comment: And in some localities within a nation, people who come from other parts of that same nation may be considered *foreigners* (usually with a negative connotation).

Comment: Attibuting negative connotations to the words *foreign* and *foreigner* and avoiding them for that reason has long struck me as silly. How ethnocentric and xenophobic does, say, an Englishman have to before he regards another man's *not* being English as a sufficiently unfortunate and embarrassing disability to require a euphemism? We now officially and ridiculously speak at my (U.S.) university of instruction in "world [not *foreign!*] languages," but the Germans seem to have no such problem with *fremden Sprachen* nor the Greeks with ξένες γλώσσες.

Comment: @BrianDonovan The problem is that the word has, in the past, been used pejoratively. Sir Cecil Rhodes opined that to be born an Englishman (not Scottish, Irish or Welsh - please note) was 'to have won first-prize in the lottery of life'. That was precisely how Victorians thought and it has taken two world wars, a century of ridicule, the European Union, and still people in the UKIP caravan talk about *Johnny Foreigner*.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Are Dakota, Narragansett, Sioux, or Navajo ‘foreign’ languages in a US university? They are certainly ‘world languages’ (as is English)—but they are, if anything, less of a foreign language in the US than English is.

Comment: Flanders & Swann summed it up nicely: www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vh-wEXvdW8  Wait for the last line.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: They are in a real sense foreign to monolingual speakers of English, such as are all too abundant here, including among the tribes in your somewhat odd list (Dakota AND Sioux?). Foreign is a relative term, and the language it belongs to sets the frame of reference: "foreign languages" means languages other than English (which is the relevant curricular category), just as *fremden Sprachen* means languages other than German and ξένες γλώσσες means languages other than Greek. "World languages" as you note includes English, and arguably excludes only Klingon.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I responded to the initial comment on my question in much the same way, pondering exactly who decided and why "foreigner" is somehow derogatory, whereas "alien" is not!

Comment: @WS2: In the Flanders & Swann number that Chenmunka points to (which is of course a vintage *satire* on English xenophobia and national chauvinism), the terms "Irishman, Welshman, or Scot" are associated with contemptible qualities. Since this has manifestly been done, do we need euphemisms for them now too?

Comment: @BrianDonovan I would say your definition of ‘foreign language’ fits when you are talking about what a foreign language is with respect to a _person_: it is basically any language that is not native to that person. When relating the term to a _place/country/area_, though, the concept of native languages is not really relevant; it then becomes (to me, at least) a term describing _indigenous_ (to varying degrees) languages, an altogether more gradual and difficult-to-pinpoint notion.